# Reading Outlook Express XP-32 DBX format and XP-64 DBX format

Tags: c++, windows-xp, outlook

I use format/sources from https://www.infobyte.hr/oedbx/ to read OE6 DBX files and it works just fine. On 32-bit version of OE6, on Windows XP 32-bit.

On 64-bit Windows XP it seems that OE6 is using slightly different DBX format. It is odd enough because it is otherwise looking the same. The format is not completely different, just slightly, but enough that my reader can't read all of the files. It can read some DBX files but not all.

Is there a more complete documentation, more complete source for reading DBX files or documented difference between the two formats I can use to adjust my code to read both formats?

Of course, I can resort to reading it using OE/Windows Mail API but then DBX files can't be read on Windows 8 or Windows 7, only on Windows XP or Vista. This is my last resort solution if I can't make the reader compatible with 64-bit format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some examination I found no documentation on 64-bit format and decided to read 64-bit format using `IStoreFolder` interface (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms710250%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Good thing is that this interface also supports reading messages from Windows Mail. Bad thing is that it does not read all database fields properly (e.g. Watch and Account cannot be read), but at least the basic message/folder data can be extracted.

Comment: @GabrielB Yes, give me the public download place and I'll put it there.

Comment: What do you mean by public download place ? Any kind of storage service would be fine. I use this one regularly for instance : http://cjoint.com/ (it's in french, choose "public" and "illimité" so that the link remains active if anybody needs that file in the future). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot, much appreciated!